# Tax conundrum on discounts

Tags: cartthrob

I want to create a £100 discount on a product costing £600 (inc tax)

In the UK I charge 20% tax so:

```
Sub Total: £600
Discount: £100
Total: £500 (£83.33 tax)
```

A sale to the USA would not include tax so:

```
Sub Total: £500
Discount: £100
Total: £400 (£0 tax)
```

The problem is that to get the £100 discount for the UK buyer I have to input £83.33 in the discount field. This actually works out the total taxes correctly but I have to multiply the discount by 1.2 to show it in the invoice as the discount is saved as £83.33 in the order channel.

The buyer from the USA now only gets a discount of £83.33 and his totals look:

```
Sub Total: £500
Discount: £83.33
Total: £416.67 (£0 tax)
```

If I input £100 as the discount value the sale to the USA is correct but the sale to the UK gets a bonus discount of £120.

```
Sub Total: £600
Discount: £120
Total: £480 (£80 tax)
```

Is there anyway around this problem?